# How to determine screen position/height of SlidingDrawer handle?

Tags: android, height, surfaceview, slidingdrawer

HI Guys,

I'm using SlidingDrawer with a custom SurfaceView and ran into a problem.
The problem is that the SurfaceView doesn't know about the remaining view area
when the handle of the SlidingDrawer is being drag up and down.

Is there a way to set my SurfaceView height base on where the handle current height?

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <and.dev.test.CustomSurfaceView android:id="@+id/flock"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<SlidingDrawer android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" android:content="@+id/content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@id/handle"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

        <TextView android:background="@drawable/bird_blue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@id/content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer> </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: FrameLayout tag is taken out for preformatted construct?

Comment: FrameLayout tag is taken out for prefformatted/code tag construct if it starts on a new line. --> BUG!

Answer (score 0):

`SlidingDrawer` can only be used as an overlay over layouts. That pretty much means that you can only put it inside a `FrameLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`.

Just put your custom `SurfaceView` and `SlidingDrawer` in a `FrameLayout` in your XML and you'll be fine and wont have to worry about resizing heights or anything.

Hope that helps

Comment: I do have SlidingDrawer in a FrameLayout, but when it is opened, the custom surfaceview is drawn over it.

I tried overriding drawer's handle's open and close interface to change the surfaceview height, however, on closing the drawer handle, the surfaceview is not drawn with correct height. It is drawn with height set when drawer was close.

Comment: it would be easier if you posted your xml layout file here